# Creating files and folders in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm newbie on WP8 and trying to build up an app which reads constant variables from XML file and write user changes to another xml file.

However, I failed to create folders or files with following code.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

        this.writeFile();

    }

    public async void writeFile()
    {
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("Values.xml");
        lblSafakCount.Text = xDoc.Descendants("isFirstUse").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();

        string input = @"<isFirstUse>NO</isFirstUse>";
        var replacement = XElement.Parse(input);;

        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        StorageFolder local = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        if (local != null)
        {
            StorageFolder sf = await local.CreateFolderAsync("Res", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            StorageFile file = await sf.CreateFileAsync("val.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }

    }
```

I've successfully read isFirstUse parameter from Values.xml so I have no problem with reading from files. When I try to examine codes step by step, app throws no error during the test but not creating folder or file.

Can you please help?
Thanks.

Comment: need function headers please, does it look like something like this? "public async Task MyWriteFunction()"

Comment: Hi, function header is "private async void writeFile()", called by main function

Comment: Codes works as programmed.  Can write those 30 or so bytes and read it back again.  Do you mean it doesn't create the folder/files on the SD Card?  I wrote both function as part of the solution and can read and write just fine.

Comment: on a side note, I believe for your code that your looking for variables that fit the local settings scenario... take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here are my read and write based on your functions

If you want to write to the SD Card more information can be found here
[Access the SD card in Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn611857.aspx)

---

```C#
public async void MyWriteFile()
{
    string input = @"<isFirstUse>NO</isFirstUse>";

    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

    StorageFolder local = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    if (local != null)
    {
        StorageFolder sf = await local.CreateFolderAsync("Res", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        StorageFile file = await sf.CreateFileAsync("val.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }

}

private async void MyReadFile()
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
    StorageFolder local = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    if (local != null)
    {
        StorageFolder sf = await local.CreateFolderAsync("Res", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        StorageFile file = await sf.CreateFileAsync("val.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, 256);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi again,

I found that the problem was with my WP8 emulator so I reinstalled the emulator several times and re-run the codes now it's working fine.

Confirmed with isolated storage tool that file and folders created.

Thanks for your help,Alparslan